# Null class to retrieve the underlying type

Tags: c#, c++

I like to know how I can do the following C# code in C++

```
object data;
private T GetJsonData<T>(String node)
{
   Type type=typeof(T);
   Type nType=Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
   if(null!=nType)
   {
      if(node=="")
         return default(T);
      return (T)Convert.ChangeType(data,nType);
   } 
}
```

I think `std` namespace should have some similar methods that can do the same but I can't find an example to do something as above.

Comment: I recommend reading [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and tell us at least what you have tried so far and where you struggle.

Comment: C++ doesn't have this kind of type reflection as provided by c#. The closest think you can have are [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, it is doable: template specialization for the basic types (int, long, ...), and then for the other types, do what the `Convert.ChangeType` does: create and use an interface like the `IConvertible`, that the type `T` must have, and that parses the string... considering how the templates are done in C++, you don't even need the interface. You can directly use a `T T.Parse(std:string)` method

Comment: I am not sure if you are having [the x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): when you say "do the following C# code in C++", do you mean "getting an object with a concrete type from string/json representation", or do you mean "use a universal convert/different-name class to perform conversions"? If it is the first meaning, this is already implemented for serializable objects (that is, objects implementing the stream i/o operators), using boost::lexical_cast.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the given code is not convertible directly into C++ as there is neither a central convert class nor is it possible to check if a type can have a nullptr value. Of course you can build both behavior on your own using mechanics like type traits:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/

You can build a nullptr checker easily on your own with function overloding:

```
inline bool canbeNULL(bool){return false;} 
inline bool canbeNULL(int *){return true;} 
// and all others...
```

the above code would look like:

```
T dummy;
if(canbeNULL(dummy))
{
  // do what you have to do
}
```

also you can wrap the different conversation functions int an own `Convert` class using method overloading.

In your example, you use a function converting JSON into c++ objects. AS JSON has only a few different types, I would resolve your problem with function overloading. As function overloading is not working with return types, you have to give the return type as parameter like:

```
void GetJsonData(std::string strin, bool &returnvalue) {do the stuff}
void GetJsonData(std::string strin, int &returnvalue) {do the stuff}
void GetJsonData(std::string strin, double &returnvalue) {do the stuff}
// and more...
```

this way, you can use the functions inside a template and the template will resolve the right call itself.